# A is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra

Let  $ f(x)= x^{n}-nx+1 $ and let $A$ be an $ n \times n $  matrix with characteristic polynomial $f$.  I am going to prove that if $n> 2$ then $A$ is diagonalizable over the complex numbers.

If we show that $f$ and $f'$ do not have common zeros can we say that $f$ has no multiple zeros namely if $ \alpha $ is a zero of f $ (x-\alpha)^{2} $ is not a divisor of $f$? So we have $n$ different eigenvalues of $f$. Hence $A$ is diagonalizable.

Also $A$ is diagonalizable if $n=2$.

Comment: *Also $A$ is diagonalizable if $n=2$*... Why is that so?

Comment: that is because we can find two linearly independent eigenvectors

Comment: No we cannot... Please check some simple examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct. Whenever the characteristic polynomial has distinct roots, the corresponding linear transformation is diagonalizable.